# Create a webservice

Tags: web-services, mono, xamarin.android

How do I create a webservice using Mono For Android? It seems like everything is about consuming a webservice, and not really about creating one.

I've tried using this: http://www.mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService

But System.Web.Services.WebService doesn't exist. System.ServiceModel hasn't been translated yet either. Does anyone have clues on how to create a webservice on Mono For Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now tried to implement the following code and tried to run it in the emulator, but the request I make either through my browser or through a REST client, never reaches the HandleRequest.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var startBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.StartBtn);
    stopBtn.Clickable = false;

    startBtn.Click += SetupListener;
}

private void SetupListener(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _httpListener = new HttpListener();
    _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9876/");
    _httpListener.Start();
    _httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleRequest, _httpListener);
}

private void HandleRequest(IAsyncResult result) {
    var context = _httpListener.EndGetContext(result);
    var response = "<html>Hello World</html>";
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

    context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Close();

    _httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleRequest, _httpListener);
}
```

I have tried making request like the following: http:// localhost:9876/ , http:// 10.1.1.190:9876/ and http:// 10.0.2.2:9876/ but none of them actually reaches into the application.

Comment: I've now created a Windows Console app to test the HttpListener. But I'm unable to connect. I'm getting a SocketException upon connect saying:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I'm trying to connect at http://localhost:9876, but it seems like the request is not passed on to the emulator and the app itself.

Comment: I found out that I needed to redirect a port using telnet client from my local machine to the emulator. Then everything worked fine.